# How do i use SQLDependency with EntityFramework NavigationProperties

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-4.1, sqldependency, navigation-properties

I am using SQLDependency for Caching purposes and EntityFramwework on top of it. Few of my entities have Navigation Properties. Which I was trying to access using Eager Loading as below

entity.Include("NavigationProperty");

and I did set IsLazyLoading = false by default.

Intenally ADO.net creates a Left Outer Join SQL Query for Include Linq query.

According to MSDN "Outer Joins" are not supported on QueryNotification. Below is the link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewzkxxh(v=vs.90).aspx

So, How do i load NavigationProperties while using SQLDependency ?

Any sort of help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yes, it's a pity that `Include` is always implemented as outer join. The only way to work around this is doing the joins yourself in linq.

Comment: @GertArnold Ya that the option i was looking at. But was wondering if there was any hack for it.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I was wanting to implement SqlDependency on my OutputCache for a site I have hosted on AppHarbor but wasn't sure if it would work or not...